# How to fire an Intent from ListAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview

Any help will be highly appreciated. I am using a ImageButton in each row of a ListView. When user presses the Button, I need to fire another activity. I have written the code

```
viewHolder.editWordButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), EditTextClass.class);
   startActivity(i);
}
});
```

But it does not identify function startActivity(i)?

Comment: why view.getContext()? it is not supposed to be v.getcontext()?

Comment: provide the rest of your code

Comment: and to start the activity you have to applied it on a context : v?getContext().startActivity(i). Hope it helped.

Comment: @JeremyD Yes; v.getContext().startActivity(i);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize that startActivity(..) is not a method of an OnClickListener? Where does startActivity(...) come from? Why it comes from [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). So knowing this, how can you start the activity, what do you need? **CONTEXT**.

Comment: @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditTextClass.class);
  v.getContext().startActivity(i);}

Answer (score 1):

because there is no such function in this class OnClickListener. Try calling it from context, or if it will not work from applicationContext

Comment: I meant that sometimes you're unable to get the context, in such cases it's helpful to call getApplicationContext() method, and call start activity on it.